# Multiple WHERE conditions on same column =val1 but doesnt=val2 or val3

Tags: mysql, join, condition, where

I am trying to filter a table which has NON-UNIQUE transaction id's, joined to a products table on 1 common column. The filter needs to be as follows:

```
equal to :group1 AND
NOT equal to :group2 AND
NOT equal to :group3
```

I originally started with the below query but without the `AND rk_group <> ____` conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT txn_id)
                    FROM 1_txns
                    INNER JOIN 2_products USING (sku)
                    WHERE rk_group = :group1
                    AND rk_group <> :group2
                    AND rk_group <> :group3
                    ;
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT txn_id)
                    FROM 1_txns
                    INNER JOIN 2_products USING (sku)
                    WHERE rk_group NOT IN ( :group2, :group3)
                    ;
```

I have also tried multiple combinations of joins and IN() and NOT IN() and it's still returning all teams ids including those where the NOT groups are present.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Schema info relevant for the query:

```
table 1_txns
(txn_id, sku)

table 2_products
(sku, rk_group)
```

Sample data

```
Txn_id, rk_group


------

    1,group1
    1,group2
    2,group1
    3,group1
    3,group3
```

If the above were my data, and group1 is my = group, and groups2 and 3 are my != groups, then I should return a row count of 1. Which is txn id '2'. All methods I've tried so far will return a count of 3.

NOTE: there are only 3 distinct rk_groups in the 2_products table.

Comment: It might be helpful if you elaborated on what you mean by "no luck"  Are you getting too many results, too few?  One thing that I see is that you aren't specifying the join logic for 1_txns and 2_products.  How are those two tables related?

Comment: Thanks and apologies. I have updated my question. I am still getting too many results. Is 'USING (sku)' not appropriate join logic?

Comment: It would be helpful if you give a sample data, and tell which rows should not be selected.

Comment: I have updated the question, excuse the formatting I'm on my mobile

Comment: I'm finding this confusing. Your query shows `group1` as an inequality, yet you say at the bottom of your post that `group1` is your equality group. You've only included sample data from one table, but there are two in your query. Based on the data you've provided at this point, the count of 3 you're receiving looks correct, as there are 3 distinct `txn_id` values with a `rk_group` of `group1`.

Comment: Imagine the data I've shown you as the join without any group by or distinct and all other columns truncated. So `txn_id` is in `1_txns` and `rk_group` is in `2_products`.  I have also edited the query, as I realised I hadn't changed the names of my variables to suit the sample data i'm presenting. apologies @Dan

Comment: This does not make sense:  `WHERE rk = 'a' AND rk <> 'b'`.  If it is 'a', it won't be 'b'.  So why do have the second test??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your WHERE clause does not make much sense, because it is applied to each row individually and it is pointless to check if the same value is equal to `a` and at the same time not equal to `b` or `c` – of course, it will not be equal to `b` or `c` if it is `a`. What you want instead, therefore, is for the conditions to be applied to a *group of rows* as a whole – more specifically, to each group of rows sharing the same `txn_id`.

So, you need to use GROUP BY and, to apply conditions to groups of rows, HAVING. This query will give you the list of `txn_id` values matching your requirements:

```
SELECT
    t.txn_id
FROM
    1_txns AS t
    INNER JOIN 2_products AS p USING (sku)
GROUP BY
    t.txn_id
HAVING
    COUNT(p.rk_group = :group1 OR NULL) > 0
    AND COUNT(p.rk_group IN (:group2, group3) OR NULL) = 0
;
```

As you do not seem to want the list, only the number of its items, use the above as a derived table to count the rows:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        txn_id
    FROM
        1_txns AS t
        INNER JOIN 2_products AS p USING (sku)
    GROUP BY
        t.txn_id
    HAVING
        COUNT(rk_group = :group1 OR NULL) > 0
        AND COUNT(rk_group IN (:group2, group3) OR NULL) = 0
) AS s
;
```

As you can see, `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is not necessary: the derived table is grouping by `txn_id` and thus cannot return duplicates – so, `COUNT(*)` is enough to get the correct result.

In case you are not aware, the `OR NULL` bit lets the COUNT function count only matches and omit mismatches, as explained in detail in this answer:

- [Why do I need “OR NULL” in MySQL when counting rows with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011311)

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation.  Thank you!

Comment: `OR NULL` does not make sense.  What are expecting it to do?

Comment: @RickJames it converts `false` to `null` so `COUNT()` doesn't couth them (the falses), only the trues.

Comment: @AndriyM you could "simplify" `COUNT(BooleanExpression OR NULL)` to `SUM(BooleanExpression)` in mysql.

Comment: @Sillycubeᵀᴹ: Very true, and I've alternately suggested the former and the latter in my answers (sometimes both). `COUNT(boolean OR NULL)` would be my personal preference, because it expresses my intention of counting better (or so I think), but I accept that there are probably many people who prefer using `SUM(boolean)` – and I can understand why they would.

Comment: @AndriyM What if I were to want to do, `A and B, but not C`. I thought that just swapping around the 2 conditions inside the HAVING COUNT(*****) parentheses might work but that doesn't seem to work. I have tried to do A&B but not C with this. [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88244/). But I can't get my head around an alternative for EXCEPT.

Comment: @AdamCopley: If both A and B are mandatory to be present, then with the method in my answer you'll need to have a separate condition for each: `COUNT(grp = A OR NULL) > 0 AND COUNT(grp = B OR NULL) > 0` (followed by `AND COUNT(grp = C OR NULL) = 0` to account for `not C`). Otherwise you could use COUNT slightly differently and cover both A and B with one condition: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN grp in (A, B) THEN grp END) = 2`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue with your current implementation is that you are not looking at other rows which match the same sku/txns, but have a different rk_group on another line matching that sku/txns.

```
SELECT
    i.sku,
    i.GoodGroup as rk_group
FROM (
    SELECT
        A.sku as sku,
        B.rk_group as GoodGroup,
        COUNT(C.rk_group) as cnt
    FROM
        1_txns as A
        INNER JOIN 2_products as B
            ON A.sku=B.sku
            AND B.rk_group = :group1 --should eliminate anything that isn't in group 1. If MySQL complains about a constant here, drop it to the `WHERE` clause
         LEFT JOIN 2_products as C
            ON A.sku=C.sku 
            AND B.rk_group <> C.rk_group --don't repeat the same entry as previous. This is redundant given the current WHERE clause
     GROUP BY
         A.sku, B.rk_group
     WHERE
         C.rk_group IN (:group2, :group3)
) as i
WHERE
    i.cnt < 1
```

You can wrap another layer around it
`SELECT COUNT( *stuff from above* )` to get your desired count of number of entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33130/discussion-between-mpag-and-adam-copley).